# Order of execution of static blocks and instance variable

Tags: java, static

```
public class H {
    static final int x;
    static {
        x=2;
    }
    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.print(new H().x);
    }
}
```

This will print **2** as o/p.

Now my question is:

We know that the static block is called first. Now if the static block is called, we are having `x=2` in that block. So how does the compiler works, because until that time we do not have definition of `x`?

Comment: Note that you could do `System.out.print(H.x);` and get the same result.  The javac compiler fakes the static reference when you use an instance reference on a static value or method.

Comment: Of course, even if `x` were not static, but were instead initialized in the constructor you'd get the same thing.

Comment: It would also work (given `x` is static) to do `H nullH = null; System.out.print(nullH.x);`.

Comment: @HotLicks   what do you mean by javac compiler fakes the static reference??

Comment: why nullH.x would work??

Comment: I mean that if you try to use a reference variable (pointer) to reference a static field or method, *javac* will take the class of the reference variable and use that to find the field/method (in fact ignoring the actual reference value).

Comment: Try it.  Then learn how to use *javap* to dump the bytecodes of a class and see what's generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static variables are initialized before static blocks are executed.  `x` is defined with a value of `0` because it's a primitive.  Then it is assigned the value of `2`.

Answer (score 0):

The `static` blocks are executed *when the class is loaded*.  This happens before your code can create an instance of the class, so by the time `new H()` executes the value is already initialized.  Also, you should not refer to static members with an instance reference.  It should just be `H.x`.

Comment: I'm not sure one can say "should not" when *javac* goes out of its way to fake things if you use a reference rather than a class to refer to a static.

Answer (score 0):

> how does compiler works because till that time we do not have definition of x

`x` is defined as a static field of `H` class:

```
public class H{
    //here is the definition of x static field
    //is uninitialized but that's not a problem for the compiler
    static final int x;
    static {
        //...
    }
}
```

Apart of that, all fields in a class are initialized with a default value. `int` fields are initialized with 0. This enables using `H.x` in any part of the code and being compilable.

About execution, check [@JimGarrison's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25211577/1065197).